VS2022 doesn't check to see if a method already exists?
I have a large project in VS2022 and have split the code into multiple .cs files for readability. When in the designer, if I want to quickly get to an element's method, I'll doubleclick the text here:
However, this takes me to the main .cs file where the method doesn't exist.
Additionally, when my Designer reloads, VS will try to create all the methods it seems to find missing and then dumps all these duplicates into the main .cs file 
And they 100% exist in other .cs files in the same namespace.
Why is VS doing this and not checking to see if the methods already exist in other files?

Do you have the class declared partial?

@TimRoberts yes - public partial class FormLeafEditor : Form

Report a problem with the Visual Studio product or installer

Is there any plugin installed? Try updating Visual Studio to the latest version, repairing , and then creating a new WinForm project to test it. Does this solve the problem?
